# Vaadin 21 Menubar vs Tabs for navigation

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin21

Context: Vaadin 21, Java 8.

On top of a Vaadin 21 sample application (from https://start.vaadin.com/app/ ) I wrote my own `RouterLayout` with navigation bar on top, body in the middle and footer at the bottom (as exchange for the `MainLayout` in the sample application).

In the navigation bar I put a `MenuBar` ( https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/menu-bar ) with some `RouterLink`s in it.

When the user clicks at one of the `RouterLink`s in the `MenuBar`, then the whole page refreshes and also my `RouterLayout` is reinstantiated (= constructor is called).

When I exchange the `MenuBar` by a `Tabs` component ( https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/tabs ), then the click at the same `RouterLink` as before just exchanges the content of the body in the `RouterLayout` (as expected).

I know this hint at https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/components/menu-bar, but I don't know why there is a difference between `MenuBar` and `Tabs`:

> Menu Bar should not be used for navigation. Use tabs for switching
> between content, or anchor elements for regular navigation.

So my questions are:

1. Why is there a difference (the page refresh) between `MenuBar` and `Tabs` in navigation, even when I use the same code for `RouterLink` creation in both cases?
2. Why should the `MenuBar` not be used for navigation?
3. Is there a way to do navigation without page refresh with the `MenuBar`?

Answer (score 3):

> Why should the MenuBar not be used for navigation?

I think the main reason is because by default the Vaadin Menu Bar does not use `<a href>` elements, but instead relies on JS event listeners. If it’s technically possible to use anchors within it, I suppose it could be fine.

Though, I would assume it would not be the best possible experience for assistive tech users, as all/most of the links would be initially hidden (you need to manually open each menu to see them).

Comment: Also, note that you will get additional tab stops when using links/anchors inside Menu Bar, which can be unexpected for the user.